# Paypal checkout can you auto expand the cart

Tags: javascript, paypal

When a user clicks Pay with Paypal button on my site, the checkout pop-up appears with no information other than the total.  If you click the cart at the top then you see details of the transaction.  Many users will not know to click the cart.   Is there a way to show this info by default?

I am using the JavaScript SDK in Sandbox mode

[image]

Sample Code:

```
  paypal.Buttons({
  style: {
    shape: 'rect',
    color: 'gold',
    layout: 'vertical',
    label: 'pay',
    
  },
 createOrder: function(data, actions) {
  // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
    
var orderDescription = "TEST "
  return actions.order.create({
    intent: "CAPTURE",
      
    
    purchase_units: [{
         amount: {
                currency_code: "CAD",
                value: "150.00",
                breakdown: {
                    item_total: {
                        currency_code: "CAD",
                        value: "150.00"
                    }
                }
            },
            items: [
                {
                    name: "Computer",
                    description: "The best item ever",
                    sku: "xyz-2654",
                    unit_amount: {
                        currency_code: "CAD",
                        value: "50.00"
                    },
                    quantity: "3"
                },
               
            ]

        }],
    payee: {
         email_address: "payee@gmail.com"
        
       },
    payee_display_metadata: {
        brand_name: "name"
    },
    
     application_context: {
                shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING",
                business_name:"name",
          "brand_name": "Name",  // SHOWS ONLY on CANCEL AND RETURN TO brand_name
     },
     note_to_payer: "Contact us for any questions on your order.",
    

    
    
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to expand it by default.

Focus on designing your site's page so that information about contents and the total is all presented clearly before the user clicks to open the payment approval window.